# powershell script Ad script group

Tags: powershell

I have the below ps script to Import users details from a domain/ forest from a domain local group, everything is working, but i need to include two more details, user mail is and user domain in the excel.  How can I do this?

```
Get-ADGroupMember "test" | Select-Object samaccountname, name, distinguishedname | Export-CSV -path "c:\test.csv" -notypeinformation
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a complicated problem.  Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I have tried multiple option and i have very limited knowledge on script coding

Comment: I have modified and tried the below script, but we have users from other forest, so those users the below script will not work because of cannot query sid

Comment: Dan- Some people are expert in different area, so asking help may not be a big deal.I am good on some technology area in which  you may not... so please do not comment if you cannot help the people

Comment: My comment is not intended to be rude; StackOverflow is a site that expects people to have made some research effort of their own before asking a question.  Your question doesn't suggest what specific difficulty you're having and doesn't suggest that you've tried anything, and so isn't what would typically be expected here.  I would guess (without having looked) that you could change the `Select-Object` to include the fields `email` and `domain` to solve your problem - have you tried something like that?

Comment: Thanks for understandiing, I have tried these parameters earlier and i get the below code in excel Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection

Comment: get-adgroupmember -Identity "testgrp" | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq "user"} | Get-ADUser -Properties SN,GivenName,Mail | Select-Object SN,GivenName,Mail | Export-Csv Exports.csv

Comment: I have also tried above, but fetching domain having problem and I think we have to filter the user domain name from distinguish name

Answer (score 0):

Some properties are not included in the default property set of a user object. In that case you need to query the user with the additional (or all) properties, e.g.:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "test" `
  | Get-ADUser -Properties * `
  | select samaccountname, name, distinguishedname, mail  `
  | Export-CSV "C:\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

AFAIK the (DNS) domain name is not an AD attribute, but you could derive it from the distinguished name:

```
(Get-ADUser "name").distinguishedName -replace '^.*?,dc=' -replace ',dc=', '.'
```

so you could add another property in the `select` statement like this:

```
@{n="domain";e={$_.distinguishedName -replace '^.*?,dc=' -replace ',dc=', '.'}}
```

As for the referral error: the group seems to be containing members from another domain. AFAIK all of the following requirements must be met to be able to run AD PowerShell cmdlets against other domains in the same forest:

- The [Active Directory Web Services must be running](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378783) on at least one of the DCs of the remote domain, and the port must be accessible from the local domain.
- Your account must have admin privileges on the remote DCs (e.g. by being a member of the Enterprise Admins group).

Comment: Thanks. I have tested above script now and earlier.I am getting  distinguishedname not  domain name. Also, users details not reflecting from other domain.

Comment: When we use -properties * get resource unavailable from other domain

Comment: Is there any function  instead of -properties *. When I give -Properies .I am getting below error and unable get users from other domain  ResourceUnavailable: (CN=user1238,OU=...=xyz,DC=local:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADReferral

Comment: SO is not a chat. Please refrain from flooding answers with comments.

Comment: Error Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.I  would to get only active users not disabled users